# Laravel Dusk on Centos: Failed connect to localhost:9515; Connection refused

Tags: laravel, centos, tdd, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

OK, today is the day. I finally started (again) to use TDD.

I notice that this thing called Dusk has appeared. Great, browser testing.

The only problem is that I get this:

Failed connect to localhost:9515; Connection refused

I did chmod 777 on the chromedriver files and still get the error.

My dev server is a Centos vm. Is this the problem?

Edit:

I think I am making some progress:

`yum install GConf2`

Now I get: 

`cannot find Chrome binary`

**EDIT**

I am back on this now.

php artisan dusk gives me:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

If I do this:

```
./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
```

I get this:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Any ideas?

Mick

Answer (score 2):

Try running: `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chrome-linux`

If you see:
`Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f) on port 9515 (or whatever port you are using)
Only local connections are allowed.`  Then it is working.  I also had to install the google-chrome binary:
[How to install 64-bit Google Chrome on 64-bit RHEL/CentOS 7](https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-redhat-centos-fedora-linux/)

The other thing to install is Xvfb.  Then you can run this command in a new terminal: `Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1280x960x24 &`

This is supposed to be the way to run this.  I however, have not been able to get this to work.  I am hoping someone can also add some input here.

Update:
I got his to work.  Make sure that nothing is running as root.

Comment: Use `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux` from Laravel 5.7+